# Installing Redis JSON on MacOSx with brew

Tags: javascript, json, python-3.x, redis, redisjson

How do you install RedisJSON on a macOSx with brew?

How do you enable modules on redis without having to compile redis?
I dont want to use docker clients

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Redis Stack is probably the easiest way to do this. It has more than just RedisJSON as it includes RediSearch, RedisGraph, RedisBloom, and RedisTimeSeries but will work just fine.

First, tap the Redis Stack Homebrew tap:

```bash
brew tap redis-stack/redis-stack
```

Next, run brew install:

```bash
brew install redis-stack
```

To start Redis you can run:

```bash
redis-stack-server
```

There are some details if you have an existing Redis installation on your Mac that you'll need to follow. Full instructions, including those details, are [here](https://redis.io/docs/stack/get-started/install/mac-os/).

Comment: How do I get  brew  to start redis-stack-server on startup now.  I had redis starting on boot. " Successfully stopped `redis` (label: homebrew.mxcl.redis)". I dont want both running.

Comment: That's a good question. I've asked internally at Redis and will report back what I find out. Frankly, this is why I just use Docker. ;)

Comment: Also, can you please link performance metrics for native vs stack-server redis.  What do I give up by using stack-server in terms of preformace/pipelining..

Comment: Redis Stack is just Redis with modules installed. Performance will be the same.

Comment: @Guy_Royse (name format makes it hard to tag you) can you take a look at this please,, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74681165/redis-javascript-zadd-is-not-a-function

Comment: Redis doesn't support service installs via homebrew. It did initially, but homebrew removed a feature and so we had to pull it.

Comment: "by service install" you mean start/stop/restart.  what would be a workaround a bash script on startup?   Need to manage local: mac/linux, cloud: linux

Comment: I upgraded. The commanr   "redis-stack-server" wont run server. 19067:M 20 Oct 2023 12:03:31.710 # Module /usr/local/Caskroom/redis-stack-server/7.2.0-v4/lib/redisearch.so failed to load: dlopen(/usr/local/Caskroom/redis-stack-server/7.2.0-v4/lib/redisearch.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /usr/local/Caskroom/redis-stack-server/7.2.0-v4/lib/redisearch.so: cannot load 'redisearch.so' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
 /usr/local/Caskroom/redis-stack-server/7.2.0-v4/lib/redisearch.so: stat() failed with errno=1

Comment: Any help? go version go1.21.3

Comment: redis standalone works fine..  loadmodules seems to be problem