# Redis: get element from JSON array by index

Tags: javascript, json, redis

The package I'm using is **redis**. I used the following command to store a JSON array in Redis:

```js
await redisClient.json.set('car.volume.tire', '$', []);
await redisClient.json.arrAppend('car.volume.tire', '$', { hello: 'there' });
```

But when I want to retrieve the element by index, I receive `null`:

```js
await redisClient.json.get(`car.volume.tire[0]`);
```

However, the following returns the full JSON array:

```js
await redisClient.json.get(`car.volume.tire`);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried: `await redisClient.json.get('car.volume.tire', { path: ['[0]'] });`? See: [_"Retrieving JSON Documents from Redis"_](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/tree/master/packages/json#retrieving-json-documents-from-redis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```js
await redisClient.json.get('car.volume.tire', { path: ['[0]'] });
```

or you can pass `path` as just a string as Guy Royse suggested:

```js
await redisClient.json.get('car.volume.tire', { path: '[0]' });
```

See: ["Retrieving JSON Documents from Redis"](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/tree/master/packages/json#retrieving-json-documents-from-redis)

---

### Full example

```js
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { createClient } from "redis";

dotenv.config();

const { REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT } = process.env;

const redisClient = createClient({
  socket: {
    host: REDIS_HOST,
    port: REDIS_PORT,
  },
});

redisClient.on("error", (err) => console.log("Redis Server Error", err));

await redisClient.connect();

await redisClient.json.set("car.volume.tire", "$", []);
await redisClient.json.arrAppend("car.volume.tire", "$", { hello: "there" });

const found = await redisClient.json.get("car.volume.tire", { path: "[0]" });

console.log(found); // { hello: 'there' }

redisClient.disconnect();
```

Comment: You can also provide a single path as just a string like this: `await redisClient.json.get('car.volume.tire', { path: '[0]' });`

Comment: @GuyRoyse Hey, I just found your [`redis-stack-server` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74630354/1762224) to get the JSON module working on Mac, Thanks.

Comment: Happy to be a small part of the solution!